# How to restore data of a shortcut file

Tags: windows, windows-7, shortcut, restore, shortcut-file

This happened about 5 years ago. I had REALLY important photos on my phone, so I decided to copy them on my laptop. But I used a paste shortcut option to paste it.
Then I deleted all of those photos from my phone. But now I need them.
Is there ANY way to restore the photos of that file (which is a shortcut now)?
My laptop is Windows 7.
They are really important to me.
Please help me.

I tried some tutorial on YouTube, but they didn't work.